# C bit boolean logic

Tags: c, boolean-logic

I have the following C statement:

```
int res = x & (x ^ y);
```

Is there a way to do the same thing, but using `x` and `y` only one time each?

For example:

```
x | (~x & y) == x | y
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, by expanding the xor (`a ^ b == (a & ~b) | (~a & b)`), and then simplifying the result, one gets:

```
res = x & ~y;
```

Answer (score 4):

`x & (x ^ y)` sets the bits that are set on `x` and set on `x^y` e.g. not set on `y`.

So you can do:

```
int res = x & ~y;
```